# How to add point to QChart when using QDateTimeAxis x-axis

Tags: python, pyside2, qtcharts

I modify code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079698/qdatetimeaxis-series-are-not-displayed)

1. I try to use `datetime.timestamp()` as x-point , but it doesn't work.
2. My totally hour is 5 hours and tickcount is 10, I expect every half hour to cut the time , but it is not.
3. how to add candlestick at specific time(maybe 8:45) to this qchart ?

```
import random, datetime
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts
from PySide2.QtCore import QPointF, Qt
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.plot = QtCharts.QChart()
        self.chart_view = QtCharts.QChartView(self.plot)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart_view)

        self.series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
        self.candle_series = QtCharts.QCandlestickSeries()
        self.series.setName("Magnitude")
        self.plot.addSeries(self.series)
        self.plot.addSeries(self.candle_series)
        # self.plot.createDefaultAxes()
        # self.plot.legend().hide()
        self.candle_series.setDecreasingColor(Qt.green)
        self.candle_series.setIncreasingColor(Qt.red)

        # Setting X-axis
        self.axis_x = QtCharts.QDateTimeAxis()
        self.axis_x.setTickCount(11)
        self.axis_x.setLabelsAngle(70)
        self.axis_x.setFormat("h:mm")
        self.axis_x.setTitleText("Date")
        self.axis_x.setMax(datetime.datetime.strptime('202005071345','%Y%m%d%H%M'))
        self.axis_x.setMin(datetime.datetime.strptime('202005070845','%Y%m%d%H%M'))
        # Setting Y-axis
        self.axis_y = QtCharts.QValueAxis()
        self.axis_y.setTickCount(7)
        self.axis_y.setLabelFormat("%i")
        self.axis_y.setTitleText("Temperature [celcious]")
        self.axis_y.setMax(60)
        self.axis_y.setMin(10)
        self.plot.setAxisX(self.axis_x, self.series)
        self.plot.setAxisY(self.axis_y, self.series)
        self.plot.setAxisX(self.axis_x,self.candle_series)
        self.plot.setAxisY(self.axis_y,self.candle_series)      
        self.candle_series.append(QtCharts.QCandlestickSet(30,50,20,25))

        self.series.append(float(QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("202005070849", "yyyyMMddhhmm").toMSecsSinceEpoch()),22,)
        self.series.append(float(QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("202005070950", "yyyyMMddhhmm").toMSecsSinceEpoch()),20,)
        self.series.append(float(QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("202005071051", "yyyyMMddhhmm").toMSecsSinceEpoch()),58,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: pyside2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> #### [datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)
>
> Return POSIX timestamp corresponding to the
>   datetime instance. The return value is a float similar to that
>   returned by time.time().
>
> Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time and this
>   method relies on the platform C mktime() function to perform the
>   conversion. Since datetime supports wider range of values than
>   mktime() on many platforms, this method may raise OverflowError for
>   times far in the past or far in the future.
>
> For aware datetime instances, the return value is computed as:
>
> ```
> (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()
> ```

As you can see from the way it calculates the time difference in seconds but according to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeaxis.html#details) that time is needed in milliseconds:

> [...] 
>   QDateTimeAxis can be used with any QXYSeries. To add a data point to
>   the series, [`QDateTime::toMSecsSinceEpoch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch) is used:
>   [...]

Considering the above there are 2 possible solutions:

- Multiply `timestamp()` by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds:

  ```
  self.series.append(
      datetime.datetime.strptime("202005070849", "%Y%m%d%H%M").timestamp() * 1000,
      22,
  )
  self.series.append(
      datetime.datetime.strptime("202005070950", "%Y%m%d%H%M").timestamp() * 1000,
      20,
  )
  self.series.append(
      datetime.datetime.strptime("202005071051", "%Y%m%d%H%M").timestamp() * 1000,
      58,
  )
  ```
- Use QDateTime:

  ```
  self.series.append(
      QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(
          "202005070849", "yyyyMMddhhmm"
      ).toMSecsSinceEpoch(),
      22,
  )
  self.series.append(
      QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(
          "202005070950", "yyyyMMddhhmm"
      ).toMSecsSinceEpoch(),
      20,
  )
  self.series.append(
      QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(
          "202005071051", "yyyyMMddhhmm"
      ).toMSecsSinceEpoch(),
      58,
  )
  ```

---

The tickCount indicates the total number of ticks, and the spacing of the ticks meets the following condition:

```
dt = (dmax - dmin) / (tickCount -1)
```

It subtracts "1" from tickCount because it also considers the extremes

```py
self.axis_x.setTickCount(11)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc ,can you help to answer the first question about add point to chart , I try to use `self.series.append(datetime.datetime.strptime('202005070849','%Y%m%d%H%M').timestamp(), 22)` to add , but doesn't work.

Comment: @RelaxZeroC I already found the solution but I'm still writing it (search for valid sources)

Comment: hello @eyllanesc   , I have third question about add candlestick to specific time , should I use .setCategories(xxx) ?