# PyQt5: How can I update a QTableView/QAbstractTableModel everytime I get data from a socket?

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt5

I have a websocket and want to update my PyQt5-GUI every time there is a new packet coming in.
There is a `QAbstractTableModel` to handle the conversion to the `TableView`.
A `QWidget` wraps up the `TableView` and Model. In this `QWidget` I started a thread to listen to the data from the socket and as args I gave it the update-function, that should update the data and the table.

`FieldTableModel` is my `QAbstractTableModel`. `packet_to_fnc` receives data from the socket, throws it in a `dict` and passes it into `update_table()`.

```
class FieldTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.field = Field(20)
        self.receiver = Thread(target=packet_to_fnc, args=(self.update_table,))
        self.receiver.start()
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.table.setModel(FieldTableModel(self.field))
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def update_table(self, packet):
        self.field.update_field(packet)
        self.table.setModel(FieldTableModel(self.field))
```

Now when I start the GUI and data from the socket comes in, I get the following message in the console for every packet:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QHeaderView(0x16b0b6f5590), parent's thread is QThread(0x16b06c2c7a0), current thread is QThread(0x16b0b7b4610)
```

So my problem basically is that PyQt doesn't like the execution of `update_table()` in the Thread.
I was also thinking of using a @property-attribute in a class, but I guess it's the same outcome?

Is there a different way to trigger the Table-Update every time there is new socket data?

Comment: this is to update a chart, but I assume, may work similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71360222/best-way-to-chart-streamed-data-using-pyqtchart-or-pyqtgraph-with-pyqt5-on-pytho

Comment: Use a QThread, with a custom signal, and connect it to the function that updates the model. Note that, unless every new packet would result in a *completely* new data layout, you should not create a new model every time, but instead update it either by inserting/removing rows and columns or by updating the data and emitting the `dataChanged` signal.